# Получить список друзей друзей используя поиск в ширину на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

Есть словарь, ключ - имя человека, значение - список его друзей

Как используя поиск в ширину найти список друзей какого-то человека и список друзей его друзей.

Я хотел чтоб возвращался словарь с ключом сколько ребер к вершине и значением список с именами

```
import collections
graph = {'Lisa Rose': ['Gene Seymour', 'Claudia Puig', 'Jack Matthews'], 'Gene Seymour': ['Claudia Puig', 'Jack Matthews'], 'Michael Phillips': ['Gene Seymour'], 'Claudia Puig': ['Lisa Rose', 'Jack Matthews', 'Toby', 'Gene Seymour'], 'Mick LaSalle': ['Michael Phillips'], 'Jack Matthews': ['Toby', 'Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose', 'Gene Seymour'], 'Toby': ['Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose', 'Jack Matthews']}

def bfs(graph, root):
    visited, queue = set(), collections.deque([root])
    visited.add(root)
    dist = {}
    distance = 0
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.popleft()
        dist[distance] = vertex
        distance += 1
        for neighbour in graph[vertex]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbour)
                queue.append(neighbour)
                dist[distance] = queue
    return dist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(bfs(graph, 'Toby'))
```

Но код что-то не правильно работает.

Comment: Добавьте пример результата. Словесное описание не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
graph = {'Lisa Rose': ['Gene Seymour', 'Claudia Puig', 'Jack Matthews'], 'Gene Seymour': ['Claudia Puig', 'Jack Matthews'], 'Michael Phillips': ['Gene Seymour'], 'Claudia Puig': ['Lisa Rose', 'Jack Matthews', 'Toby', 'Gene Seymour'], 'Mick LaSalle': ['Michael Phillips'], 'Jack Matthews': ['Toby', 'Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose', 'Gene Seymour'], 'Toby': ['Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose', 'Jack Matthews']}


res1 = graph[input()]
res2 = set()

for el in res1:
    res2.update(graph[el])

print(res1)
print(res2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот доработанный пример. `visited` хранит посещённые узлы, `queue` - пары `(узел, расстояние)`. Когда узел выбирается из очереди, все его соседи вставляются с очередь с увеличенным на единицу расстоянием. Условие `not in visited` перенесено, оригинальный вариант мог выдавать один и тот же узел в ответ несколько раз. Ответ накапливается в `answer` в виде словаря `расстояние -> [узел, ...]`:

```
import collections


def bfs(graph, start):
    answer = {}
    visited = set()
    queue = collections.deque([(start, 0)])
    while queue:
        node, dist = queue.popleft()
        if node not in visited:
            visited.add(node)
            answer.setdefault(dist, []).append(node)
            queue.extend((n, dist + 1) for n in graph[node])
    return answer


graph = {
    'Lisa Rose': ['Gene Seymour', 'Claudia Puig', 'Jack Matthews'],
    'Gene Seymour': ['Claudia Puig', 'Jack Matthews'],
    'Michael Phillips': ['Gene Seymour'],
    'Claudia Puig': ['Lisa Rose', 'Jack Matthews', 'Toby', 'Gene Seymour'],
    'Mick LaSalle': ['Michael Phillips'],
    'Jack Matthews': ['Toby', 'Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose', 'Gene Seymour'],
    'Toby': ['Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose', 'Jack Matthews']
}
print(*bfs(graph, 'Toby').items(), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> $ python bfs.py 
> (0, ['Toby'])
> (1, ['Claudia Puig', 'Lisa Rose', 'Jack Matthews'])
> (2, ['Gene Seymour'])
> ```